# Kaa TCP Ports and services

Tags: tcp, ports, kaa

I installed an instance of Kaa in AWS, and by following the instructions all the ports listed below were set as open, however I wanted to know which service is running under each port to know exactly if all of the ports need to be open to be accessed outside my network, or if only those ports for some particular services need to be open outside my network. I could find info for 6 of them, anyway please confirm if you can:

```
>PORT   SERVICE
>22
>8080   Admin UI
>9999   Operations Server
>9998
>9997   Operations Server
>9889   Bootstrap Server
>9888   Bootstrap Server
>9887
>9080   Sandbox
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

22 - it's port for ssh.(use this [link](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=22) for more details )

9998 and 9887 ports don't used from kaa 0.8.0 version (for more details use [official documentation page](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Transports#Transports-Defaulttransports))

Bootstrap ports - 9889, 9888

Operations ports - 9999, 9997

you can change ports of bootstrap and operations services in this files:

- bootstrap-http-transport.config
- bootstrap-tcp-transport.config
- operations-http-transport.config
- operations-tcp-transport.config